# Удаление программы после ее закрытия

Tags: bat

Нужно написать bat, который будет открывать программу, а после закрытия программы удалять ее исполняемый файл и удаляться сам. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [How to make .BAT file delete it self after completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2888976/2881286)

Answer (score 0):

Пакетный файл 'MY_NAME.bat' запускает 'FILE_NAME.exe':

```
@ECHO OFF
start /wait FILE_NAME.exe

:_del0
DEL /Q /F FILE_NAME.exe
IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 goto ok0
GOTO _del0
:ok0

:_del1
DEL /Q /F MY_NAME.bat
IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 goto ok1
GOTO _del1
:ok1
```